# Effect of snow on BVOC emmisions of plants/trees

Tags: biogeochemistry, snow, carbon

Plants re-emit a substantial fraction of their assimilated carbon into the atmosphere as Biogenic Volatile Organic Compounds (BVOCs) that affect the chemical and physical properties of the atmosphere.

If these plants/other similar vegetation have snow in there vicinity then what are the effects on the BVOC emissions from those plants. That is if a vegetation grows over a snow covered mountain then will the BVOC emissions be any different if there would have been no snow?

Comment: Welcome at Earthscience.SE. For clarification: Do you mean a situation when snow or something else is covering the vegetation (i.e. leafs) or do you mean a situation when it is cold (cold enough for snow to fall)?

Comment: @daniel.neumann Both. I am talking about permanent as well as non-permanent snow.

Comment: What type of BVOC and what type of plant? For example, isoprene and monoterpenes will follow different mechanisms. A good paper on this topic is http://www.atmos-chem-phys.net/6/3181/2006/acp-6-3181-2006.pdf

Comment: @BarocliniCplusplus In general for all kinds of BVOCs emission. Same is the case for plants. It can be herbaceous vegetation like grasslands, lichens/mosses, forests(evergreen and deciduous). To be more precise, the vegetation in the Himalayan region. Although it itself covers a wide range of varieties.

Comment: @BarocliniCplusplus And thank you for the paper. It's really interesting.